# How to add Sort Function with Query Function In Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Please help me how can I add SORT function in this.
`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OmVZFtG9p510jmTI23FvIzz8T5urZUAj7VYce__Cg_Y/edit#gid=0" , "Sheet1!A2:J");IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yGh_DaXD7A4lUY47Vk-CdRAAJsZ0fnPxDanH6qMiYTI/edit#gid=0" ,"Sheet1!A2:J");IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kKHJk3LmHYsPTAAtxhoUBkF-JykyEiMUI-ioSQYEODQ/edit#gid=0" , "Sheet1!A2:J")},"select * where Col1 is not null or Col2 is not null or Col3 is not null or Col4 is not null or Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null or Col6 is not null or Col7 is not null or Col8 is not null or Col9 is not null or Col10 is not null")`

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SORT(QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1OmVZFtG9p510jmTI23FvIzz8T5urZUAj7VYce__Cg_Y", "Sheet1!A2:J");
 IMPORTRANGE("1yGh_DaXD7A4lUY47Vk-CdRAAJsZ0fnPxDanH6qMiYTI", "Sheet1!A2:J");
 IMPORTRANGE("1kKHJk3LmHYsPTAAtxhoUBkF-JykyEiMUI-ioSQYEODQ", "Sheet1!A2:J")},
 "where Col1 is not null 
     or Col2 is not null 
     or Col3 is not null 
     or Col4 is not null 
     or Col5 is not null 
     or Col6 is not null 
     or Col6 is not null 
     or Col7 is not null 
     or Col8 is not null 
     or Col9 is not null 
     or Col10 is not null"))
```